# How to move an 'user.config' file from source PC to target PC preserving its settings?

Tags: .net, windows, app-config, appsettings, user-config

I have a 3rd party application, **Remove Empty Directories** aka **RED** which can be downloaded here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/rem-empty-dir/files/?source=navbar

The user settings of the application follows the standard .Net settings infrastructure, it saves its settings in a directory like this:

> ...\AppData\Local\RED2\RED2.ex_Url_ilre4odeu2sx2xsqyulyx2jybty45cd5\2.2.0.0

My problem is that I will make the `ignore_directories` setting perssistent inside the **user.config** file when I move the application folder to another PC, I mean that I will preserve the user settings of the source PC when I move the app and the settings file to the target PC, but of course I can't just copy the folder that stores the **user.config** file because the **user.config** settings will be automatically stored in a new folder with a new hash totally different from the source PC, so the old **user.config** file in the target PC will be ignored ...not recognized.

This is the default content of the **user.config** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="RED2.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <RED2.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="last_used_directory" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\RED2\RED2.ex_Url_ilre4odeu2sx2xsqyulyx2jybty45cd5\</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="infinite_loop_detection_count" serializeAs="String">
                <value>10</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="pause_between" serializeAs="String">
                <value>80</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="max_depth" serializeAs="String">
                <value>-1</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ignore_directories" serializeAs="String">
                <value>System Volume Information
RECYCLER
Papierkorb
Recycled
NtUninstall
$RECYCLE.BIN
GAC_MSIL</value>
            </setting>
        </RED2.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

This is the content that I will make perssistent/portable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="RED2.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <RED2.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="last_used_directory" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="infinite_loop_detection_count" serializeAs="String">
                <value>10</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ignore_0kb_files" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="pause_between" serializeAs="String">
                <value>80</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="max_depth" serializeAs="String">
                <value>-1</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="keep_system_folders" serializeAs="String">
                <value>False</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ignore_directories" serializeAs="String">
                <value>$RECYCLE.BIN
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WinJS.2.0_1.0.9600.16384_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe\microsoft.system.package.metadata
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Device Stage
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\DRM
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\IdentityCRL
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\RAC\Temp
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\DRM
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Sqm
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Microsoft\CLR_v2.0
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Feeds Cache
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\AppCache
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Application Shortcuts
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Burn
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\ThumbCacheToDelete
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Notifications
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\AccountPictures
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Printer Shortcuts
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent
C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows
C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows
C:\Users\Public
C:\Windows\assembly
C:\Windows\Downloaded Program Files
C:\Windows\Help
C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel
C:\Windows\Installer
C:\Windows\Logs
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly
C:\Windows\Offline Web Pages
C:\Windows\Resources\Themes\aero
C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles
C:\Windows\servicing
C:\Windows\System32\catroot
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\CLR_v4.0
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SystemCertificates
C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\Temp
C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles
C:\Windows\System32\Microsoft\Crypto
C:\Windows\System32\ProximityToast
C:\Windows\System32\RasToast
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\CLR_v4.0_32
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\AppData\LocalLow\Microsoft
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\DriverStore\FileRepository
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ProximityToast
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\RasToast
C:\Windows\Temp
C:\Windows\WinSxS\Backup
C:\Windows\WinSxS\InstallTemp
C:\Windows\WinSxS\Temp
System Volume Information</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="delete_stats" serializeAs="String">
                <value>3496</value>
            </setting>
        </RED2.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

My question is, I can override the settings file properties or other workaround that could make the **user.config** file really portable avoiding the problem of the directory hash?

Well, I'm pretty sure its possibly because I did it in the past with another **user.config** file of another .Net app, I can't remember exactly what I did because it was a lot of trial and error, but I think what I did was creating a new **app.config** file in the same directory of the application folder and just copying the full content of the **user.config** stored in *AppData* directory to my new **app.config** file in the app's working dir, then editing at my desire the properties inside the **app.config** file to preserve a custom default value when the app creates the **user.config** in the *AppData* directory for first time ran, but that technique didn't worked this time for this application **RED2.exe**.

I tried some basic ideas like adding the **user.config** in the same folder where the **RED2.exe** is stored then adding in the file the configuration I like, also I did the same thing creating an **app.config**, anything worked, but maybe I did something wrong during the procedure.

Comment: Don't hard code the path. Use `User Settings`. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: user.settings are, as the name says, designed to be for one specific user. If you want to get a portable version I would suggest you take care of the settings by yourself using a json serialize or something similar.

Comment: @Console My intention is to add the application into a personalized installer (using InnoSetup) then, at install time I could run an automated tool developed in .Net (VB.Net or else C#) that could do the trick, the question is... How to?. But anyways I think this could be done without that kind of interaction, without developing an app, just designing a proper app.config or user.config file content that will perssist when copying it to another PC (because again I mention I did it in the past). Thanks!

Comment: @theghostofc Sorry but did you read the part where I mention its a 3rd party app?, I don't have a source code where to use the settings infrastructure. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @ElektroStudios, sorry, I missed that part. My bad! RED2 code is available on Github https://github.com/hxseven/Remove-Empty-Directories. You may download and tweak it a bit. :)

Comment: wha!! how you find it?, very good to know, thanks a lot because that solves the problem ...I'll made the necessary modifications in the source then problem solved, but since I have made a very specific question I would like to know anyway the solution to my question. I keep trying to find out. Thanks again man!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier for you if you have access to the code. RED2 code is available on Github [here](https://github.com/hxseven/Remove-Empty-Directories). You may download and tweak it a bit to suit your purpose.

> This is not a link-only answer. As a solution to a specific problem, access to the code is the best solution in this case. I am just sharing a link to the publically available codebase for everyone to know.

Comment: I said bounty reward sorry I were have a confussion because in other question where I have a bounty. thanks again,

Comment: @ElektroStudios, no worries. I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by downloading the source code at https://github.com/hxseven/Remove-Empty-Directories and building a default **ExeName.exe.config**, then in its `userSettings` section I can modify the settings to preserve a default custom configuration when copying the app directory to another PC, just including the **ExeName.exe.config** that contains the per user settings, its very easy.

The trick to do it was that.

It doesn't seems to differ from the **user.config** file that is generated inside the Local AppData folder when per user settings are saved, so I suppose that just an easier way will be to perform the desired modifications under the UI to generate the file in the AppData fiolder, and then rename the generated **user.config** file to **RED2.exe.config** and store it in the app's working dir, then copy it to another PC.